# Magento 2.2.5 Error in Exception Log Every Night

Tags: magento2.2, magento-2.2.5, reports

I'm getting an error in `exception.log` every night.

Error is

> main.CRITICAL: Directory "/tmp/analytics/tmp" cannot be created  {"exception":"[object] 
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException(code: 0): Directory \"/tmp/analytics/tmp\" cannot be created

It happens when the cronjob Magento\Analytics\Cron\CollectData executes but var/tmp/analytics/tmp does exist and has permissions set to 775

I think it relates to Advanced Reporting because when I try to access it, I get the 404 page on https://advancedreporting.rjmetrics.com

How would I go about solving this ?

Comment: Please try to set var director permission to  777. Sudo chmod 777 var  -R

Comment: Hello, doesn't that mean anyone has full access to var/backups as well?

Comment: Did anyone get solution here ? I am getting same issue in M.2.4.X. Also created directory in /var/ and on root manually with 755 permission, but still having same error log.